# Using "data-href" to load an image into a DIV

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a link that, when clicked, will load an image into a DIV. Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/kgvux/

JQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(".link").click(function (e) {
        var url = $(this).data('href')
        $('.enclosure').load(url)
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
.enclosure {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.link {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="enclosure">
    <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67419000/jpg/_67419697_hull-getty.jpg">
</div>
<div class="link" data-href="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/67424000/jpg/_67424686_67424685.jpg">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `.load()` for images. Also, the request will fail either way due to cross-origin restrictions.

Instead, change the `src` property of the image:

```
$(function () {
    $(".link").click(function (e) {
        var url = $(this).data('href')
        $('.enclosure img').prop('src', url)
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just because I never know that. What would in this case be the difference in using `prop` over `attr`?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: There's no difference here, but I tend to use `prop` wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be updating the img element's src attribute:

```
$('.enclosure img').attr("src", url);
```